# textView getLineCount under for loop

Tags: android, textview

I want to count the lines when I will set multiple texts and also do something when it will have more than 3 lines.

Here is what I have tried so far..

```
private void addComment(String comment){
tComment.setText(comment);
tComment.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new
                    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Log.d("Comment is-->",tComment.getText().toString());
            lineCnt = tComment.getLineCount();
            if (lineCnt > 3) {
                Log.d("Comment","up to 3 -->"+lineCnt);
                tComment.setSingleLine(false);
                tComment.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                tComment.setLines(3);

            }else{
                Log.d("Comment"," -->"+lineCnt);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**I have called this addComment method multiple times(under for loop)**
its only giving me the count of the last text I have set.

please consider with providing any helpful way,thanks

Comment: Please me more specific about what you want to do here.  "Do something" isn't really helping me understand.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish in the 4 lines of code when lineCnt > 3?

Comment: thanks, I am trying to make the textView property Ellipsize with end (means it will look like text..) only when the lines are more than 3 (not for any short string). Please ask me if you have any other question

Comment: And so what is it doing instead that you're not expecting?

Comment: its only giving me the count of the last text I have set but I want each time I set a new text, it will give me the counted lines.

Comment: I don't think you can knoww ahead of time how a string will render.  I think you have to set the string into the textview and wait for it to measure before you can ask how many lines it takes.